# Split irregular text into table

Tags: r

I have text-tables that look like this:

```
in.data <- rbind(
c("ColA KB      Col C    The ColE (2.0)"),
c("abc  def     ghijklm  n    opqrst"), 
c("uv   wx y    zzzzzz   aa   bcd"),
c("ab   cd               gh   jklmn")
)
```

And I need it like this:

```
wanted.result <- rbind(
    c("abc", "def", "ghijklm", "n", "opqrst"), 
    c("uv", "wx  y", "zzzzzz", "aa", "bcd"),
    c("ab", "cd", NA, "gh", "jklmn")
)
colnames(wanted.result) <- c("ColA", "KB", "Col C", "The", "ColE (2.0)")
```

What makes this complicated is that the vertical split-delimiter locations can be based both on the column-names and on the column contents.

Here is one ugly attempt that works:

```
library(stringr)
spaces.1 <- unique(unlist(str_locate_all(in.data[1,], " ")))
spaces.2 <- unique(unlist(str_locate_all(in.data[2,], " ")))
spaces.3 <- unique(unlist(str_locate_all(in.data[3,], " ")))
spaces.4 <- unique(unlist(str_locate_all(in.data[4,], " ")))
spaces.12 <- spaces.1[spaces.1%in%spaces.2]
spaces.123 <- spaces.12[spaces.12%in%spaces.3]
spaces.1234 <- spaces.123[spaces.123%in%spaces.4]
for (i in length(spaces.1234):2) {
    if (spaces.1234[i]-spaces.1234[i-1]==1) spaces.1234[i] <- NA_integer_
}
delimiters <- na.omit(spaces.1234)
library(data.table)
in.data.table <- data.table(in.data)
in.data.table[, col.1:=substr(V1, start=1, stop=delimiters[1])]
in.data.table[, col.2:=substr(V1, start=delimiters[1], stop=delimiters[2])]
in.data.table[, col.3:=substr(V1, start=delimiters[2], stop=delimiters[3])]
in.data.table[, col.4:=substr(V1, start=delimiters[3], stop=delimiters[4])]
in.data.table[, col.5:=substr(V1, start=delimiters[4], stop=37)]
setnames(in.data.table, as.character(in.data.table[1, ]))
wanted.result.2 <- in.data.table[2:4, 2:6, with=FALSE]
```

But I need to do this thousands of times, and with varying amounts of columns and rows.

Is there a better way to do this, that also works for any amounts of rows?

Update: To clarify, the problem is to find the widths, based on locations of spaces in the header and the rows. Sorry for not being clear about that.

Comment: The process requires a rule to determine when and how many NA values to fill in.

Comment: Isn't this just a fixed-width text file essentially? - e.g. - `?read.fwf` should be able to cope with it.

Comment: I think read.fwf requires the widths, which are not known beforehand in my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume that any column that contains a space in all rows separates fields and we assume that the last field is 10 wide or less (change this number if need be).  No packages are used.

```
w <- diff(Reduce(intersect, gregexpr(" ", paste("", in.data))))
w <- c(w, 10)
X <- read.fwf(textConnection(in.data), w, skip = 1, as.is = TRUE)
names(X) <- trimws(read.fwf(textConnection(in.data), w, n = 1, as.is = TRUE))
X <- X[names(X) != "NA"]
X[] <- lapply(X, trimws)
```

giving:

```
> X
  ColA  ColB   Col C ColD ColE (2.0)
1  abc   def ghijklm    n     opqrst
2   uv wx  y  zzzzzz   aa        bcd
3   ab    cd           gh      jklmn
```

**Note:** We used this as the input in the test run above:

```
in.data <-
structure(c("ColA ColB    Col C    ColD ColE (2.0)", "abc  def     ghijklm  n    opqrst", 
"uv   wx  y   zzzzzz   aa   bcd", "ab   cd               gh   jklmn"
), .Dim = c(4L, 1L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `read.fwf` after figuring out the column widths using a `gregexpr` call looking for something that defines column names:

```
txt <- paste(c(in.data),collapse="\n")
widths <- diff(c(gregexpr("Col", in.data[1])[[1]], nchar(in.data[1])+1))
out <- read.fwf(textConnection(txt), widths=widths, skip=1)
names(out) <- unlist(read.fwf(textConnection(txt), widths=widths, n=1))
out

#  ColA  ColB     Col C     ColD  ColE (2.0)
#1 abc   def      ghijklm   n         opqrst
#2 uv    wx  y    zzzzzz    aa           bcd
#3 ab    cd                 gh         jklmn
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that not all column names start with col. I will change that in the example.

Comment: @Chris - well, if there's no clear rule for how the columns are defined, you're going to have to get the widths manually. No program can be a mind reader.